# How to remove 404 file not found error when trying to recieve json array from url?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to get the JSON response, which is in an array format. This JSON response I want to convert in Java array.

This is the array:

```
[{"id":"1","Name":"Daniyal"},
 {"id":"2","Name":"Aslam"},
 {"id":"3","Name":"Kamal"},
 {"id":"4","Name":"Asghar"},
 {"id":"5","Name":"Jamal"},
 {"id":"6","Name":"Suraj"},
 {"id":"7","Name":"Mujji"}]
```

And this is the code:

```
try {
    URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("http://xenzet.com/ds/ds.php?");

    String readLine = null;
    HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();

    conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conection.setRequestProperty("userId", "a1bcdef"); // set userId its a sample here
    int responseCode = conection.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + urlForGetRequest);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    //print in String
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    //Read JSON response and print
    JSONArray myResponse = new JSONArray(response.toString());
    System.out.println("result after Reading JSON Response");


} catch (Exception ex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what issue you are facing here. Any Exceptions ?

Comment: i want to recieve all the above data and then i will put names in array not using id for the moment but still in handy and i am getting 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with reading from that URL is that apparently the "User-Agent" request header is required. I managed to read your JSON with the code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class JsonReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader();
        jsonReader.read("http://xenzet.com/ds/ds.php?");
    }

    public void read(String url) throws IOException {
        URLConnection urlConnection = getUrlConnection(url);
        String json;
        try (InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
            json = readContent(inputStream);
        }
        System.out.println("JSON: " + json);
    }

    private String readContent(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private URLConnection getUrlConnection(String url) throws IOException {
        URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        return urlConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using java ide for core and desktop applications and java reader is not getting resolved , how to work in simple ide

Comment: yes urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); gave response data

Answer (score 0):

```
You can user JSONArray
e.g- 

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
and afterwords you can parse that json arrray object using 

ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
    listdata.add(object.optString("n")); 
}

return listdata;
```